# Green execution arrow in ddd is not visible

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, nasm

I am new in `linux assembly`. I am using `nasm` and `ddd` for debugging. I am not able view the execution indicator i.e. green arrow while step execution.

Please can anybody suggest what is the problem?

```
OS : Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit
DDD : 3.3.12
gdb : 7.4-2012.04
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ddd. gdb is happier if you add `-F dwarf` to Nasm's command line (lowercase 'f' selects output format uppercase 'F' selects debug info format). If you're using gcc to link it, adding `-g` will tell gcc to pass debug info to the executable (ld will do it unless you tell it `-s`). If you're not doing that, it might help...

Comment: Thanx for reply.. But i need GUI and it is provided by DDD..

Answer (score 0):

The green arrow is only visible in the machine code window, not in the source window. Check in the view menu to ensure you have the machine code window open (Alt+4)